# Call web API from MVC site that is authenticated with Facebook

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm not an expert in security, so I would like to validate the options here because I'm a bit lost in all the possibilities.

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application, and added Facebook authorization to it (there will be others as well, like Microsoft Mail, and integration with an Azure AD). So users currently can click the 'Log In' button, then click the 'Facebook' button; they redirect to Facebook, enter their credentials, and finally come back to my site where they are authenticated. This works fine, and in the claims I receive nameidentifier and email address.

Now I want to add a ASP.NET Core Web API, which is called by the MVC site (and later by other consumers).

As I have to implement my own authorization mechanism in the web API, I was thinking on passing the authentication token from MVC site to the web API, so that in the web API i know the authenticated user, and based on the nameidentifier I find in the token, I handle authorization for this user.

Is the solution that I propose here feasible for my scenario? Or do you handle this kind of situation typically in another way? Demo applications that I can have a look at maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the solution that I propose here feasible for my scenario? Or do you handle this kind of situation typically in another way? Demo applications that I can have a look at maybe?

Yes, you could use [**Oauth 2.0 on-behalf-of flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to achieve your idea. The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API. The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain.

Here is work flow:
[image]
1.The client application makes a request to API A with the token A (with an aud claim of API A).
2.API A authenticates to the Azure AD token issuance endpoint and requests a token to access API B.
3.The Azure AD token issuance endpoint validates API A's credentials with token A and issues the access token for API B (token B).
4.The token B is set in the authorization header of the request to API B.
5.Data from the secured resource is returned by API B.

You can refer to the code sample: [Calling a web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore).